# Add subfolder of multiple folders to path

Tags: windows, path, env

I'm trying to add the `files/` subdirectory from every directory in `site-packages/` so I can console entry points from install packages. I tried using `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\*\files\`, but didn't have any luck.

I've tried poking around for answers, but couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to do this, exactly? I think [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/569466/add-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories-to-the-path-variable-with-a-single-entry) on [SU] is similar.

Comment: I think this is answer for your question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61907/how-do-i-create-a-directory-in-all-subdirectories